# How to use evaluation metrics in RNN LSTM networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am not able to generate the metrics to evaluate my model. I've done all the tests, even reformulated the reshape. Can someone help me?
Data normalization

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

(233634, 15)
(233634,)
(100129, 15)
(100129,)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
normalizador = MinMaxScaler()
x_train= normalizador.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = normalizador.fit_transform(x_test)
y_train = y_train.values.reshape(-1,1)
y_test = y_test.values.reshape(-1,1)

x_train= x_train.reshape(1, 233634, 15)
y_train= y_train.reshape(1, 233634, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(1, 100129, 15)
y_test = y_test.reshape(1, 100129, 1)
```

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.3))

model1.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.3))

model1.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.3))

model1.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.3))

# Camada Final
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model1.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model1.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: What do you mean "I am not able to generate the metrics"? What metric values do you get? Or what happens instead?

Comment: I cannot generate Confusion, Accuracy, Precision and ROC Curve Matrix.